# DTLS: OpenSSL and mbedTLS keying material

Tags: openssl, mbedtls

I have a client which uses mbedTLS and server which uses OpenSSL libraries. After performing DTLS handshake I'm trying to get keying material with next function calls

mbedTLS:

```
mbedtls_ssl_export_srtp_keys
```

OpenSSL:

```
SSL_export_keying_material
```

But returned values are different hence I am not able to encrypt/decrypt messages. If I am using OpenSSL for client implementation then all the thing are going good and encryption/decryption works as expected.

Does someone know what could be the reason of the behavior above?

Comment: Where do you find the function `mbedtls_ssl_export_srtp_keys`? SRTP is not supported by Mbed TLS yet. There is an outstanding PR for that, in https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/pull/1540 , but it is not ready yet, and not fully tested